# Can a Sefardi name a baby after a living Ashkenazi?

Tags: minhag, names, baby-infant

I believe that Ashkenazim generally have a minhag that it is not allowed to name babies after a living person, whereas Sefardim do name after living people.  Can a Sefardi name a baby after a living Ashkenazi?

Comment: I don't believe there's any issue, per se, but it would be in bad taste to name someone after an individual who doesn't want that honour in their lifetime.

I know a couple where he's Sepharadi and she's Ashkenazi and her family made her promise not to name any of her kids after them, so long as they were alive

Comment: Just to be clear and avoid a common misperception: Sephardim name after living OR dead people.  My 3 siblings and I were named after 2 living grandparents and 2 dead grandparents.

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi I assumed that Sephardim name after dead people as well